# JQuery animated background affecting content floated above it

Tags: jquery

I've set up a jQuery animation to change background image on a div at the header of a site.

The image is larger than its container, and when animating this causes (for the duration of the animation) the elements around it to be hidden briefly.

I've probably missed something obvious, can anyone help?

jQuery below and example here:

(example now removed, but can be replicated by animating the background image of a div with another div (with background) floated over the top)

```
var currentBackground = 1;

function changeHeader() {
currentBackground++;
    if (currentBackground>6) currentBackground = 1;

        jQuery('.slider').fadeOut(1000,function() {
            jQuery('.slider').css('background', 'url(\'/myurl/images/sliders/home- slide'+currentBackground+'.jpg\') no-repeat center');
            jQuery('.slider').fadeIn(1000);
    });

    setTimeout(changeHeader,10000);
}


jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   setTimeout(changeHeader,10000);
})
```

Comment: You shouldn´t call `setTimeout()` twice and not within the function itself.

Comment: What do you mean by I've probably missed something obvious, can anyone help? how can we come to know about what problem you are facing while this animation... can please explain.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, all sorted now, I'll post when my 6hour limit is up!

Comment: Stefan, what should I use instead to trigger the repeat of the animation instead of setTimeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, many thanks to Aram for the code and Stefan for making me think about it a little differently.

Trick is to set a Z-Index lower than other page elements in the JQuery statement as below (it doesn't seem to work when just applied to the css class):

```
var currentBackground = 1;

function changeHeader() {
  currentBackground++;

  if (currentBackground>6) currentBackground = 1;

     jQuery('.slider').fadeOut(1000,function() {
        jQuery('.slider').css({'background-image': 'url(\'/myurl/images/sliders/home- slide'+currentBackground+'.jpg\')',
                               'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                               'background-position': 'center',
                               'z-index': '-1'});
        jQuery('.slider').fadeIn(1000);
  });

  setTimeout(changeHeader,10000);
}


jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   setTimeout(changeHeader,10000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

somthing like this, you can give a `background-image` a size

```
if (currentBackground>6) currentBackground = 1;

        jQuery('.slider').fadeOut(1000,function() {
            jQuery('.slider').css({'background-image': 'url(\'/myurl/images/sliders/home- slide'+currentBackground+'.jpg\')',
                                   'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                                   'background-position': 'center',
                                   'background-size': '100px 100px'});
            jQuery('.slider').fadeIn(1000);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help, Aram, the background size gave me issues with the aspect ratio of the images, but I've found that forcing the Z-Index in the JQuery CSS statement fixes it (this was seemingly getting ignored during the fade)...

Answer (score 0):

`$.fadeOut()` used `opacity` and that affects your menu `#nav` that´s located above the slider `#slider_1`.